# Creating a GroupBox with _createChildControlImpl()

Tags: qooxdoo

I tryed to create a group box with the `_createChildControlImpl()`-Methode but the layout looks like crap as you can see her http://tinyurl.com/odzgy3v

But when I implement it without `_createChildControlImpl()` it works fine: http://tinyurl.com/kwzvdm2

Could anybody please tell me what's the reason for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your browser console - there is already a hint.

When you introduce child controls qooxdoo can't reuse the former default appearance of widgets because the appearance id changed (from `"groupbox"` to `"widget/groupBox"`). So you have to add your own [appearance theme](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/4.0/pages/desktop/ui_appearance.html) (which can simply forward by using an alias):

```
   qx.Theme.define("test.myAwesomeTheme", {
     extend : playground.theme.Appearance,
     appearances :
     {
       "widget/groupBox" : "groupbox",
     }
   });
   qx.theme.manager.Appearance.getInstance().setTheme(test.myAwesomeTheme);
```

I'm extending [`playground.theme.Appearance`](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/application/playground/source/class/playground/theme/Appearance.js) here which extends [`qx.theme.indigo.Appearance`](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/theme/indigo/Appearance.js) which again extends [`qx.theme.simple.Appearance`](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/theme/simple/Appearance.js). And their you have the groubox definition we are forwarding to.

Here is the [complete playground sample](http://tinyurl.com/ps39b7n).

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to implement _createChildControl, but not call it directly. Instead call getChildControl in your constructor and let it call _createChildControl, if needed, since it is also caching the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're right it is better to just call getChildControl(). But if I do so the layout of the GroupBox still looks bad http://tinyurl.com/odzgy3v Do you have an idea what's the reason for this?

Comment: Probably late, but if you either use a `Composite` instead of a `GroupBox`, or specify a convenient `contentPaddingTop` for the `GroupBox`, the layout will look good.

The most likely reason (IMO) is that internally the `GroupBox` uses a `Canvas` layout, with subclasses expected to take over the logic of positioning controls properly within that layout, taking into account differences in height and width between various controls, whereas `Composite` does this all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

GroupBox seems to be a bad fit for what you want - it seems to assume identically sized and shaped elements inside its frame sub-widget, when filled from within the implementation of `_createChildControl()`.

Use another Composite() inside the main container instead, add "Registration" as yet another child control of type label as the first child of the custom widget, and things will look much better (although not identical).

Quick and sloppy proof of concept: http://tinyurl.com/m7ykhta